# Field: Illegal value

Tags: 7

I have a user registration form, which requires one of the fields (select list) to be populated pro grammatically from a third party service.

```
  // NOTE: Customize the exiting area drop down programmatically from aquarius tables
  $lang = $form['field_area']['#language'];
  $form['field_area'][$lang]['#options'] = array_merge($form['field_area'][$lang]['#options'], $rows);
```

This works - at least renders fine - however when I submit the form if I select anything other than the default (hardcoded) item I get a validation error:

**Area: illegal value**

How do I circumvent this check for this single field

Alex

Comment: You could _probably_ hack a way to circumvent it, but I think you are getting this error because the array you're using to populate #options is something other than a format Drupal expects.  What does the array look like?

Comment: It's a standard PHP array when populated through the form builder interface:

Comment: Through [this module](https://drupal.org/project/form_builder)? By 'standard', do you mean, it looks like `array(0 => 'Option 1', 1 => 'Option 2')` or `array('option1' => array('a', 'b', 'c'), 'option2' => array('d','e','f'))`?

Comment: Try to use drupal_map_assoc. `$form['field_area'][$lang]['#options'] = drupal_map_assoc (array_merge($form['field_area'][$lang]['#options'], $rows));`

Comment: By the user profile module I assume? Yes it appears to be a standard (flat) PHP associative array not modified with custom drupal attributes or values.

Comment: I give up...while it circumvents the validation is causes this error:

Notice: Array to string conversion in drupal_write_record() (line 7101 of C:\Wamp\apache\htdocs\drupal\includes\common.inc).

And doesn't seem to persist the selection either...I will hardcode the list - thanks anyways

Comment: I'm pretty sure that confirms that the array you're getting from the 3rd party must be modified to be Drupal ready.  Good luck though.

Comment: I would agree, but I tried drupal_map_assoc() and looked at the array when populated by drupal itself and compared it to the array after I modified it and they are identical array structures - in anycase I just manually populated the list for now I'll readdress this at a later time I suppose. Thanks for your help :)